# Bootstrap 4 and height of multiple elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

Its hard for me to explaint what i want, so i made a mocup 
[image]

How to make that with bootstrap 4? So goal is that those 4 elements on the right are all the time (except on mobile) equal height like element on the left (image). Can someone help with that? Here is makrup for now.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <section class="hero">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-md-8"><img src="http://placehold.it/700x300/ccc/333.png?text=placeholder" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-md-4">
          <div class="contentMy">somthing</div>
          <div class="contentMy">somthing</div>
          <div class="contentMy">somthing</div>
          <div class="contentMy">somthing</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap 4's new **flexbox** utility classes. The `d-flex` class is used for `display:flex`, and then `flex-column` is used to set `flex-direction: column`..

```
<div class="container">
    <section class="hero">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-md-8"><img src="" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col col-md-4 d-flex flex-column">
                <div class="contentMy h-100">somthing</div>
                <div class="contentMy h-100">somthing</div>
                <div class="contentMy h-100">somthing</div>
                <div class="contentMy h-100">somthing</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/YyTEyi4IcU

Comment: ty so much. I'm trying to figure out everything on new bootstrap, but i didn't figure out that :)